# Copiar conteúdo de arquivo para área de transferência no Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, área-de-transferência

Olá, estou fazendo um software para um fórum, onde os membros consultam os padrões de postagens pelo software, estou armazenando esses padrões em arquivos e pedindo o Python para ler esses arquivos e exibi-los, assim o usuário copia o padrão.

Agora quero pedir para o Python copiar o conteúdo do arquivo do padrão para a Área de transferência (que é o copiar e colar). Assim não precisando do usuário selecionar o texto e copiar, quero que o software faça isso sozinho, mas como faço isso? Pesquisei muito e não achei.

Vou deixar um *print* da saída de dados que eu quero copiar para o (copiar colar do Windows).
Ignorem as outras marcações.

[saida de dados http://www.imgfans.com.br/i777/SirGates/erro.png](http://www.imgfans.com.br/i777/SirGates/erro.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usei esse código:

```
import clipboard

clipboard.paste() 
with open('teste.txt', 'r') as f:
     conteudo = f.read()     
     clipboard.copy(conteudo)
```

Segui [esse vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0_AWhpBBMvU) para instalar o Clipboard.

No vídeo, tu então no DOS e entra em C:/PythonXX/Scripts e da o comando `pip install clipboard`

Answer (score 2):

Para Windows pode-se usar o módulo [`win32clipboard`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32clipboard.html), se preferir uma alternativa *cross-platform*, o módulo [`pyperclip`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyperclip/).

Exemplo de uso do módulo `win32clipboard` (não testado):

```py
import win32clipboard

win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()

with open('arquivo', 'r') as f:
   conteudo = f.readlines()
   win32clipboard.SetClipboardText(conteudo)
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
```

Comment: o win32clipboard dá erro... Fala que o nome desse módulo não exite.. Vou tentar o outro

Comment: @LeonardoVIlarinho Esse módulo faz parte do [PyWin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/).

Comment: Resolvi usando o Clipboard... Esse aí para copiar dentro do arquivo precisa ter dois parâmetros, o tipo e o arquivo (eu acho) daí tentei um monde de vezes e não consegui